# How do I do nested routers?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I want to do nested route in my react application. For exemple, I am in a catalog backoffice/catalog, and I want to edit one product and be redirected, inside the catalog component to backoffice/catalog/editProduct.

So it will be a relative route from the route /catalog/anything, and the mother component of my EditProduct component would be the component Catalog.

Here is my App general component:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./components/Static/Home.js";
import { Dashboard } from "./components/Backoffice/Dashboard.js";
import { Catalog } from "./components/Backoffice/catalog/Catalog.js";
import { Login } from "./components/Login/Login.js";
import { Signup } from "./components/Signup/Signup.js";
import { PrivateRoute } from "./components/PrivateRoute.js";
import "./scss/App.scss";
import {Header} from "./components/Structure/Header";
import {BOHeader} from "./components/Structure/Backoffice/Header";
import {List} from "./components/Listing/List";

function App()
{
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-content">
          <Switch>
              <Route path='/backoffice' component={BOHeader} />
              <Route path='/' component={Header} />
          </Switch>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
              <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
              <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />
              <Route path='/listing' component={List}/>
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/backoffice' component={Dashboard}/>
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/backoffice/catalog' component={Catalog}/>
          </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And I would like to do something like this in my Catalog component for example to be able to access product edition in my catalog with the url backoffice/catalog/editProduct:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {List} from './List';
import {Edition} from './Edition';
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

export class Catalog extends React.Component
{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Catalog Managment</h1>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/listProducts' component={List} />
                    <Route exact path='/editProduct' component={Edition} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you and your brain ! :)

Comment: take a look https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting .... this will help you if you understand flow of route.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I understand so much better now the flow of nested routes. However, I still have an error:

Attempted import error: 'useRouteMatch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Is my version of react-router-dom to old ?

Comment: please take a look i posted a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58405339/6544460

Answer (score 0):

[image]
This is the final hook added to this release, useRouteMatch gives you access to the match property without rendering a `<Route>` component. It matches the URL just like a Route would and it accepts an exact, strict, path and sensitive options just like a `<Route>`. Before V5.1 the ways to access the match object are through:

```
- Route component as this.props.match
- Route render as ({ match }) => ()
- Route children as ({ match }) => ()
- withRouter as this.props.match
- matchPath as the return value
```

**<= V5.0**

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <Route
                    path="'/Movies/:id/'"
                    strict
                    sensitive
                    render={({ match }) => {
                        return match && <Movies match={match} />;
                    }}
                />
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**> V5.1**

```
function App() {
    let match = useRouteMatch({
        path: "/Movies/:id/",
        strict: true,
        sensitive: true
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {match && <Movies match={match} />}
        </div>
    );
}
```

for your better understanding go through this once [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)